# Parsing arguments dynamically into a method in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a quick framework for myself an thing are pretty much in place but i have a few issues here.

1. When the URL is parsed, here is the convention `http://example.com/controller/method/(param)/(param)/(param)`. I used a `switch` statement over the length of the `url` array

**Here is the code**

```
switch (count($this->_url)) {
        case 5:
            //Controller->Method(Param1, Param2, Param3)
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}($this->_url[2], $this->_url[3], $this->_url[4]);
            break;

        case 4:
            //Controller->Method(Param1, Param2)
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}($this->_url[2], $this->_url[3]);
            break;

        case 3:
            //Controller->Method(Param1)
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}($this->_url[2]);
            break;

        case 2:
            //Controller->Method()
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}();
            break;

        default:
        $this->param = $this->_url[1] .','. $this->_url[2];
            $this->_controller->index();
            break;
    }
```

Here is my question, if for example i have a forum `http://example.com/forum` from the `switch` it will run the default which is the controller `index()` method. Due to the switch chunk, i cannot have something like this `http://example.com/forum/$id` because index doesn't take in any parameter and practically i can't write different methods for each forum id. A way around it is creating a `p` method in the class and parsing in the arguments as appropriate the url will now be like `http://example.com/forum/p/$id` but i don't really like the p in the url

**Here is what i tried**
Above the switch chunk i checked if the method (gotten from the 1 index of the url) exist. If it doesn't, it should grab the extra parameter and make them arguments for the index method.

```
$this->param = NULL;
    $ct = 1;
    for ($ct; $ct < count($this->_url); $ct++) {
        if(isset($this->_url[$ct]) && $this->_url[$ct] != null) {
            if (!method_exists($this->_controller, $this->_url[$ct])) {
                $length = 0;
                $this->param .= $this->_url[$ct].', ';
            }
        }
    }
```

and the default switch condition will now be `$this->_controller->index($this->param);`
It works fine by grabbing the parameters but it is seen as just one argument i.e trying to get it out using `index($id, $section)` if the result from the `$this->param = "24, general"` The general is not seen as `$section` from the `index($id, $section)` method rather the `24, general` is seen as `$id` in the `index($id, $section)`.

I want to parse each of the gotten `$this->param` as an argument in the `index()` method.

Thanks and sorry for the lengthy question.

Comment: See [reflection method](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php). Should be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `call_user_func_array`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->_controller, $this->_url[1]), $this->_url);
// this will pass all all params to the defined function
```

Maybe you need to modify it a bit for your special needs but generally this will work for your case.

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks but comparing `call_user_func_array()` with the reflection method someone stated above which do you think is application effective?

Comment: Reflections, in my opinion, are overpowered in this case. Reflections are mainly designed to "parse" your code, for reverse engeneering or something similar. See http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php  `call_user_func_array` doesn't have that overhead of parsing the whole class itself.