# Appending post title to URLs in a custom built framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Using Stack Overflow as a case study, put this in a URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670861` it will change the URL to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670861/parsing-arguments-dynamically-into-a-method-in-php` when it loads.

How can I achieve that functionality?

I am using a custom built framework.

Here is the `.htaccess` rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$   public/    [L]    
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1  [L]
```

In the public directory, I have this `.htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is what i use to capture the incoming url in my Bootstrap class for routing.

How can I with this kind of framework achieve the functionality mentioned above. Will this routing effect still make it work because I have tried some re-write rules in the `public/` directory but it seems not to have any effect on the URL at all (I guess it's because it a framework right)

Here are a few rules I tried

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[0-9a-zA-Z-]$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/[0-9A-Za-z-]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/?title=$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
#RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

None came close to working.

Edit: my question is in no way related to its flag. I am not talking about pretty links. The framework offers that already but just like the Stack Overflow scenario described, if I go to `www.example.com/news/1` it should redirect (maybe; I don't know how Stack Overflow did it) to `www.example.com/news/1/title-of-the-new`.

Comment: I doubt it is a duplicate sir! My question is quite different from that.

Comment: Is it a crime to ask questions when i get stuck? I know what mod_rewrite cannot do without seeing that link you put there. At least stackoverflow uses the functionality i am asking help about so i still don't see a relevance of that post to what i am asking.

Comment: I need clear understanding of how stackoverflow does it and see if i can do the same (in my custom built framework).

Comment: And i don't see a reason why you should vote down my question when you don't fully understand it.

Comment: you would need  php controller to add the extra part into your url

Comment: Thank @charlietfl you seem to be making my day by your comment? how do i go about that?

Comment: would have to see if the final part exists in segment after the ID , if not redirect to the final url that includes the last section. htaccess can't do that part...it doesn't know what to add

Comment: I am not sure i understand your last comment.

Comment: well the section with the question title in it would come from database so htaccess can't do that part but php can

Comment: Okay, so the stackoverflow's own seems to be PHP not htaccess right?

Comment: Using Firebug to watch network..if I remove the last part of url on this page and only leave the number and load that .... I see  a 301 redirect to the final full url. That 301 would have to be done in php with `header('Location: .....')`

Comment: Okay thanks!!! What an answer!!! Can you detail your answer so i can mark it as correct. I will tweak my controller class to handle things like this. If i have any issue i will come back here to ask and please standby to help instead of those marking me down without fully understanding my question.

Comment: @PaulCrovella can you please remove the duplicate you have flagged on this question? Or are you still not convinced that it is not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the stackoverflow example , your php routing controller would need to take the ID part of the url and look up the last title part.

You would then have to do a `header('Location:'. $fullUrl);` redirect.

If you remove the title section of url on this page you can see in browser dev tools network that a 301 redirect is done to get to the full url also.

Comment: I'd add for the OP that a common mistake with a `header()` redirect is not adding `exit()` afterwards - as soon as you've issued the redirect, close the application down.

Comment: @halfer you are trying to say this is how it should be right? `header('Location: '.$fullUrl)`; exit();

Comment: @Prodigy yes, and of course do any application close-down that you would normally do. The main point is not to output any HTML or run any other controller actions, as it can give rise to race conditions that are hard to debug.

Comment: Okay, got it but you added another keyword I have never heard in my life - what is race condition (for the purposes of learning)

Comment: Didn't see your latest message @Prodigy (always use `@halfer` to ping me). A race condition is where two parts of a computer system will execute something but they are not synchronised, and so the order in which will happen (and thus the result) is considered undefined. The race condition in this case is: will the browser client receive the redirect and disconnect before the web app runs something that it should not? (Normally a disconnect stops the PHP application, unless it is configured not to).